# How to get the count of an InstrumentedList in Python SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following lazy relationship in my SQLAlchemy model:

```
class AuthorModel(db.Model):
    books = db.relationship("BookModel", backref="authors", lazy=True)
    def bookCount(self):
        return self.books.count()
```

I would like to get books count of the author but instead I get the following error:

```
TypeError list.count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should use "return len(self.books)"

Comment: `return len(list(self.books))` wroks for me. Thanks.